# React on Google Cloud | How to Authenticate Users with Google Email Address

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a basic React app with create-react-app command and deployed it to Google Cloud(App Engine). What are my options for adding authentication for my app on GCP? I would like for users to sign in with their Google email account before being able to use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers multiple methods of authenticating users in Cloud Platform applications. Please check here the methods:

[Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#firebase_authentication),
[Google Sign-In](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#google_sign-in),
[OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#oauth_20_and_openid_connect),
[Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/#users_api)

Comment: in my specific case i had to use IAP(cloud identity proxy) on google cloud for user management. Followed this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users#cloud-identity-aware-proxy